# Where does a value type-variable - which is returned by ref - live? Stack or heap?

Tags: c#, pass-by-reference, heap-memory, stack-memory, c#-7.2

I recently heard about the new C# Feature in 7.2, so that we now can return a reference of value type (for example `int`) or even a readonly reference of a value type. So as far as I know a value type is stored in the stack. And when the method is left, they are removed from stack. So what happens with the int when the method `GetX` exits?

```
private ref int GetX()
{
    // myInt is living on the stack now right?
    int myInt = 5;

    return ref myInt;
}

private void CallGetX()
{
    ref int returnedReference = ref GetX();
    // where does the target of 'returnedReference' live now? 
    // Is it somehow moved to the heap, because the stack of 'GetX' was removed right?
}
```

I'm getting the error

> Error CS8168: Cannot return local 'myInt' by reference because it is not a ref local (11, 24)

So why does it not work? Does it not work just because the variable can not be moved to the heap? Is this the problem? can we only return value types by reference if they do not live in the stack? I know that this are two question in one.

First: Where do value type-variables returned by ref live? Stack or heap? (I guess on the heap but why)?

Second: Why can a value type created on the stack not be returned by reference?

So this is able to be compiled:

```
private int _myInt;

private ref int GetX()
{
    // myInt is living on the stack now right?
    _myInt = 5;

    return ref _myInt;
}

private void CallGetX()
{
    ref int returnedReference = ref GetX();
    // where does the target of 'returnedReference' live now? 
    // Is it somehow moved to the heap? becase the stack of 'GetX' was removed right?
}
```

If I understand your comments right it is because now the _myInt lives not inside the method `GetX` and there fore is not created in the stack right?

Comment: Heaps vs stack are just implementation details and has nothing to do with the problem

Comment: "So as far as i know a value type is stored in the stack." - wrong.

Comment: Okay a value type-variable does not always live on stack right? It depends on where they are created? Local variable in method or object member etc.?

Comment: [See Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/reference-semantics-with-value-types#ref-readonly-returns) "You may also want to return a value type by reference, but disallow the caller from modifying that value. Use the ref readonly modifier to express that design intent."

Comment: In practice it also depends on use in lambda's, async methods etc. In theory it is totally up to the whims of the compiler.

Comment: From [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/ref-returns) : _The return value must have a lifetime that extends beyond the execution of the method. In other words, it cannot be a local variable in the method that returns it. It can be an instance or static field of a class, or it can be an argument passed to the method. Attempting to return a local variable generates compiler error CS8168, "Cannot return local 'obj' by reference because it is not a ref local."_

Comment: @MichaelRandall Could you please further explain? I don't understand what you mean whit "implementation details"

Comment: @Thangadurai Will `_myInt ` usage in  `GetX()` prevent garbage collection of the object then until the caller execution is finished? How does it affect GC?
Separately, I don't think this question should be closed.

Comment: The new `ref` syntax enables the runtime to use pointers.  Pointers can generate more efficient code, they can avoid having to copy a value, but they are dangerous.  Using a pointer to a memory location that is no longer valid is a very traditional bug.  The C# compiler checks for those kind of bugs, it can tell that the local variable no longer exists after the method returns.  So flags it as bad code.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer

Comment: The stack is an implementation detail, by Eric Lippert, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-one/

Comment: @HansPassant I don't understand why C# designers would introduce this feature but leave out a return by `const ref`. IIRC, there is such a feature in C++ to extend the lifetime of a temporary

Comment: Check https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/On-NET/Lesser-known-features-of-C-7 for more information on why ref exists

Comment: It is notable that all of these popular "it is an implementation detail" comments do not at all help to understand `ref`.  No longer a irrelevant detail anymore, you really do have to understand where variables are stored to have any hope of understanding the restrictions.  It did not make the C# language any prettier, only ever use it after you found out that you have a perf problem and a profiler told you about it.

Comment: @HansPassant absolutely agree on all points, however in this case it makes more sense to talk about its life time apposed to where it is stored, to understand the compiler error

Comment: @HansPassant re "No longer a irrelevant detail anymore, you really do have to understand where variables are stored to have any hope of understanding the restrictions." - that ship sailed a long time ago; simply ask "why can't I use `ref` or `out` (or now: `in`) on an `async` method, or a `yield return` iterator block?"

Comment: @HansPassant "The new ref syntax enables the runtime to use pointers." - the runtime has *always* been able to use pointers - both "managed pointers" (that we would call `ref Foo` in C#) and unmanaged pointers (anything involving `Foo*` in C#). The new `ref` syntax simply allows C# to use some of the features that have *always existed* in the runtime. The point is that "managed pointers" in the runtime are only well-defined *on the stack* (not on the heap), and historically C# hasn't had a mechanism to enforce the complex rules for that, so kicked that problem down the road.

Comment: Hmm, the syntax is useful to remove some of the chronic mystique about pointers.  Such as assuming that C# code ever uses unmanaged pointers (Foo* is a managed pointer) and that creating a pointer to a heap object would be invalid (fixed or GCHandle.Alloc is fine).  And getting programmers past the `unsafe` mental barrier, they are always very reluctant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel like you understand yourself already why it does not work. You cannot return *local variable* by reference from method (unless it's ref local), because in most cases lifetime of local variable is the method, so its reference outside of method does not have any meaning (outside of method this variable is dead and location where it were before might contain anything). As documentation states:

> The return value must have a lifetime that extends beyond the
>   execution of the method. In other words, it cannot be a local variable
>   in the method that returns it

In practice some local variables might live longer than execution of method they are declared in. For example, variables captured by closure:

```
int myLocal = 5;
SomeMethodWhichAcceptsDelegate(() => DoStuff(myLocal));
return ref myLocal;
```

However, this introduces additional complications without any benefits, so this is also forbidden, even though lifetime of `myLocal` might be much longer than containing method.

It's better to not think about it in terms of stack and heap. For example you might think that you cannot return reference to something allocated on stack from the method via `ref return`. That's not true, for example:

```
private void Test() {
    int myLocal = 4;
    GetX(ref myLocal);       
}

private ref int GetX(ref int i) {            
    return ref i;
}
```

Here `myLocal` is clearly on stack, and we pass it by reference to `GetX` and then return this (stack allocated) variable with `return ref`.

So just think about it in terms of variable lifetimes and not stack\heap.

In your second example, lifetime of `_myInt` field is clearly longer than execution of `GetX`, so there is no problem to return it by reference.

Note also that whether you return value type or reference type with `return ref` doesn't make any difference in context of this question.

Answer (score 4):

> So as far as I know a value type is stored in the stack.

and thus is the basis of your confusion; this is a simplification that is *grossly inaccurate*. Structs *can* live on the stack, but they can also live:

- as field on objects on the heap
- as fields on *other* structs that are (etc etc) a field on an object on the heap
- boxed on the heap (directly, or via either of the above)
- in unmanaged memory

You're right, though: if you passed a `ref return` *out* of a method, to a local *inside* a method, you will have violated stack integrity. That's precisely why that scenario *isn't allowed*:

```
ref int RefLocal()
{
    int i = 42;
    return ref i;
    // Error CS8168  Cannot return local 'i' by reference because it is not a ref local
}
```

There *are* some scenarios when the compiler can prove that even though it was stored as a local, the lifetime was was scoped to this method; it helps that you can't reassign a `ref` local (to be honest, this check is a key reason for this restriction); this allows:

```
ref int RefParamViaLoval(ref int arg)
{
    ref int local = ref arg;
    return ref local;
}
```

Since `ref int arg` has lifetime that isn't scoped to the method, our `ref int local` can inherit this lifetime in the assignment.

---

So what *can* we usefully return?

It could be a reference to *the interior of an array*:

```
ref int RefArray(int[] values)
{
    return ref values[42];
}
```

It could be a field (not property) on an object:

```
ref int ObjFieldRef(MyClass obj)
{
    return ref obj.SomeField;
}
```

It could be a field (not property) on a struct *passed in by reference*:

```
ref int StructFieldRef(ref MyStruct obj)
{
    return ref obj.SomeField;
}
```

It could be something obtained from an onward call *as long as the call doesn't involve any ref locals known to point to locals* (which would make it impossible to prove validity):

```
ref int OnwardCallRef()
{
    ref MyStruct obj = ref GetMyStructRef();
    return ref obj.SomeField;
}
```

Here again note that the lifetime of the local inherits the lifetime of any parameters passed into the onward call; if the onward call involved a `ref`-local *with constrained lifetime*, then the *result* would inherit that constrained lifetime, and you would not be able to return it.

And that onward call could be, for example, calling out to structs held in unmanaged memory:

```
ref int UnmanagedRef(int offset)
{
    return ref Unsafe.AsRef<int>(ptr + offset);
}
```

So: lots of very valid and useful scenarios that don't involve references to the current stack-frame.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer. I learned a lot about this topic. But since @Evk made reference to the Stack/Heap-Question, which I obviously had a wrong understanding of, I chose his question as the correct answer. One thing left. Why can I not return a property (int) by reference? Is it because it's actually a get_method, where you can not know if a field is returned or again a local variable?

Comment: @Daniel a "get" method *that isn't a `ref int` get* returns a *copy* of the value on the stack, so: it can't be a reference to the underlying value. Which may or not actually exist - it could be a computed property: `public int Area => Width * Height;`

Comment: Thank you for explaining. That makes sense!